# Simple injector - create a generic decorator for EF Core caching

Tags: c#, .net-core, simple-injector, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to implement caching for EF Core in my .NET Core project using Simple Injector as my DI. I'm using the CQRS pattern so I have a bunch of queries I'd like to cache (not all).

I have created a generic interface for a cached query, which takes a return type of the query, and the query arguments:

```
public interface ICachedQuery<T, P>
{
    T Execute(P args);

    string CacheStringKey { get; set; }
}
```

And here is one of my queries:

```
public class GetAssetsForUserQuery : ICachedQuery<Task<List<Asset>>, User>
{
    readonly IDataContext dataContext;
    public string CacheStringKey { get; set; }

    public GetAssetsForUserQuery(IDataContext dataContext)
    {
        CacheStringKey = "GetAssetsForUserQuery";
        this.dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public async Task<List<Asset>> Execute(User user)
    {
        var allAssets = dataContext.Assets.ToList();
        return allAssets;
    }

}
```

My decorator is not too relevant in this case, but it here is the signature:

```
public class CachedCachedQueryDecorator<T, P> : ICachedQuery<T, P>
```

I register my query and decorater in `Startup.cs` like so:

```
Container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICachedQuery<,>), typeof(CachedCachedQueryDecorator<,>));

Container.Register<GetAssetsForUserQuery>();
```

And I inject my `GetAssetsForUserQuery` like so:

```
readonly GetAssetsForUserQuery getAssetsForUserQuery;

        public GetTagsForUserQuery(GetAssetsForUserQuery getAssetsForUserQuery)
        {
            this.getAssetsForUserQuery = getAssetsForUserQuery;
        }
```

But my decorator is never hit! Now, if I register my query to the interface `ICachedQuery` in `Startup.cs` like so:

```
Container.Register(typeof(ICachedQuery<,>), typeof(GetAssetsForUserQuery));
```

And I inject `ICachedQuery` instead of `GetAssetsForUserQuery`, then my decorator is hit. But `ICachedQuery` is a generic so I can't have it resolve for one specific query.

I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my decorator is never hit!

That's correct. To understand why this is the case, it's best to visualize the object graph that you wish to be constructed:

```cs
new GetTagsForUserQuery(
    new CachedCachedQueryDecorator<Task<List<Asset>>, User>(
        new GetAssetsForUserQuery()))
```

> ***PRO TIP:*** *For many DI-related problems, it is very useful to construct the required object graph in plain C#, as the previous code snippet shows. This presents you with a clear mental model. This not only is a useful model for yourself, it is a useful way of communicating to others what it is you are trying to achieve. This is often much harder to comprehend when just showing DI registrations.*

If you try this, however, this code won't compile. It won't compile because `GetTagsForUserQuery` requires a `GetAssetsForUserQuery` in its constructor, but a `CachedCachedQueryDecorator<Task<List<Asset>>, User>` is not a `GetTagsForUserQuery`—they are both an `ICachedQuery<Task<List<Asset>>, User>`, but that's not what `GetTagsForUserQuery` requires.

Because of this, it is technically *impossible* to wrap `GetAssetsForUserQuery` with a `CachedCachedQueryDecorator` and inject that decorator into `GetTagsForUserQuery`. And the same holds when you would be resolving `GetAssetsForUserQuery` directly from Simple Injector like this:

```cs
GetAssetsForUserQuery query = container.GetInstance<GetAssetsForUserQuery>();
```

In this case you are requesting a `GetAssetsForUserQuery` from the container, and this type is compile-time enforced. Also in this case it is impossible to wrap `GetAssetsForUserQuery` with the decorator while preserving `GetAssetsForUserQuery`'s type.

What would work, though, is requesting the type by its *abstraction*:

```cs
ICachedQuery<Task<List<Asset>>, User> query =
    container.GetInstance<ICachedQuery<Task<List<Asset>>, User>>();
```

In this case, you are requesting an `ICachedQuery<Task<List<Asset>>, User>` and the container is free to return you *any* type, as long as it implements `ICachedQuery<Task<List<Asset>>, User>`.

Same holds for your `GetTagsForUserQuery`. Only when you let it depend on `ICachedQuery<,>`, makes it possible to decorate it. The solution is, therefore, to register `GetAssetsForUserQuery` by its abstraction:

```cs
Container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICachedQuery<,>),
    typeof(CachedCachedQueryDecorator<,>));

Container.Register<ICachedQuery<Task<List<Asset>>, User>, GetAssetsForUserQuery>();
```

Here are a few tips, though:

- Whether or not your queries (I typically call them the 'handlers', but what's in the name) are cacheable or not is an implementation detail. You shouldn't have to define a different abstraction for cacheable queries, and consumers shouldn't have to be aware of that.
- Instead of exposing a separate `CacheStringKey`, try using the `P args` as the cache key. This can be done, for instance, by serializing the `args` to a JSON object. This makes caching more transparent. In case the `args` object is very complex, the number of cache entries will be too big anyway, so you typically only want to cache results of very simple `arg` requests.
- Whether or not to cache, is rather an implementation detail that either should be incorporated in the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), or part of the query (handler) implementation. I typically do this by marking that implementation with an attribute, but an interface can work as well. You can then apply the decorator [conditionally](https://simpleinjector.org/aop#applying-decorators-conditionally).
- Prevent supplying full blown entities both as input and as output for your query (handlers). Instead use seperate data-centric POCOs (like DTOs). What does it mean to send a `User` as input? It's much clearer, though, when you send a `GetAllUserAssets` object. That `GetAllUserAssets` can probable just contain a `UserId` property. This makes it very easy to turn this object into a cachable entry. The same holds for output objects. Entities are very hard to cache reliably. This is much easier with POCOs or DTOs. They can be serialized with much less effort and risk.

I've written about CQRS-styled architectures in the past myself. See for instance [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/queries/). That article explains some of the points summed up above.

Comment: Finally Steven! I've been waiting for you to answer my question all day! Lol. Thanks for your very detailed answer. Could you just confirm that my architecture around how I'm trying to implement caching is the right way to go?

Comment: Hi @Viqas. That's not something I can confirm. For the very least, you should address the points mentioned at the bottom of my answer.